# Unexpected C function pointer definition syntax error in struct

Tags: c

GCC reports this weird syntax error when I include the header file in a specific file.

Error:

```
In file included from ../src/libscws/rule.h:17,
                 from ../src/libscws/scws.h:16,
                 from ../src/libscws/scws.c:20:
../src/libscws/../cjson/cJSON.h:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘sz’
../src/libscws/../cjson/cJSON.h:59: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘void’
```

cJSON.h:

[image]

Include source:

```
  8 #ifndef _SCWS_RULE_20070525_H_
  9 #define _SCWS_RULE_20070525_H_
 10 
 11 
 12 #ifdef __cplusplus
 13 extern "C" {
 14 #endif
 15 
 16 /* xtree required */
 17 #include "../cjson/cJSON.h"
 18 #include "xtree.h"
 19 
 20 #define SCWS_RULE_MAX     32
 21 #define SCWS_RULE_SPECIAL   0x80000000
 22 #define SCWS_RULE_NOSTATS   0x40000000
```

Comment: It may be that `size_t` is not defined. Try including `stddef.h` before all your other headers.

Comment: @JS1 wow, works like charm. Thanks! Still can't understand why GCC complains syntax error rather than `size_t` is not defined. You can write an answer so I can resolve the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that `size_t` is not defined.  Try including `stddef.h` before all your other headers.